# Error on run command doctrine:schema:update symfony

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

i have a Symfony project and wheni run command doctrine:schema:update or doctrine:schema:create i got this  error :
 Attempted to load class "BigIntType" from namespace "Doctrine\DBAL\Types". i have no column with type BigInt and also i run  clear:cache command multiple time but problem exisit

Answer (score 0):

i search and don't found any thing ,finally i delete vendor folder and run `composer install` command and problem solved for me